# R shiny dateRangeInput update based on input file

Tags: r, date, range, shiny

I'm trying to make a shiny app that would take user .tsv file as input, 
take a look in one defined column to decide on time range and then let the user select subset from this time range.

I am able to load in the user file, find the minimum and maximum date in the file.

I thought that it will be possible to use this information to set the min/max and start/end values in the `dateRangeInput()`.

Yet the fields are blank even after file input is loaded. I cannot have these dates set in global.R or anywhere else, since this will change with each uploaded file.

User file simplified example:

```
V1  V2  V3
7753    7 Jan 14    09:50:00
7754    7 Jan 14    09:55:00
8366    9 Jan 14    12:55:00
8471    9 Jan 14    21:40:00
8472    9 Jan 14    21:45:00
8552    10 Jan 14   04:25:00
8553    10 Jan 14   04:30:00
```

(real one has more columns, but that is unimportant here)

server.R (please excuse the probably very over-complicated way of getting the min/max, I will use `min()` and `max()` next time :) ):

```
library(shiny)
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME") #this bit here is to have the correct locale
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30 * 1024 ^ 2) #file-size limit
#loading in the file from user
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  myData <- reactive({
    inF <- input$inFile
    if (is.null(inF))
      return(NULL)
    data <- read.delim(inF$datapath, header = FALSE)
    data
  })
 #getting the minimum date appearing in the file 
  output$datRangeMin <- reactive({
    inF <- input$inFile
    if (is.null(inF))
      return(NULL)
    insidedatRangeMin <- head(c(sort(unique(as.Date(myData()$V2,format = "%d %b %y")))), n=1)
    insidedatRangeMin
  })

   #getting the maximum date appearing in the file 
  output$datRangeMax <- reactive({
    inF <- input$inFile
    if (is.null(inF))
      return(NULL)
    insidedatRangeMax <- tail(c(sort(unique(as.Date(myData()$V2,format = "%d %b %y")))), n=1)
    insidedatRangeMax
  })


})
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)


shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fileInput("inFile", "Upload monitor file:"),

  dateRangeInput('expDateRange', label = "Choose experiment time-frame:",
                 start =  'datRangeMin', end =  'datRangeMax', 
                 min =  'datRangeMin', max =  'datRangeMax',
                 separator = " - ", format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                 language = 'cz', weekstart = 1
  ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput('datRangeMin'),
      verbatimTextOutput('datRangeMax')


    )
  )
)
```

Thank you very much for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `updateDateRangeInput` can only update the selected values and the labels (ref: [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/update-input-demo.html)), you can solve this with a `renderUI`:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fileInput("inFile", "Upload monitor file:"),
    uiOutput("dates")
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30 * 1024 ^ 2) 

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  myData <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$inFile, "Select a file to load")
    )
    inF <- input$inFile
    read.delim(inF$datapath, header = FALSE)
  })

  output$dates <- renderUI({
    dates <- as.Date(myData()$V2, format = "%d %b %y")
    minval <- min(dates)
    maxval <- max(dates)
    dateRangeInput('expDateRange', label = "Choose experiment time-frame:",
                   start = minval, end = maxval, 
                   min = minval, max = maxval,
                   separator = " - ", format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                   language = 'cz', weekstart = 1
    )
  })
})
```

Comment: This is just what I needed! Thank you for the answer! So If I get it correctly, I need to reactively create the UI based on the file? It makes sense now. Thank you again!

Comment: @jprov on the *contents* of the file, yes.